# Pass data from js file to livewire component

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-livewire

I need your help. I've been trying for hours to pass a variable from my JavaScript file to a Livewire component without success.

In my JS I have the following

```
Livewire.emit('handleValue', value);
```

Error message

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Livewire.emit is not a function

I have also tried the following

```
window.livewire.emit('handleValue', value);
```

Error message

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'emit')

Can anyone help me with this problem? My app.layout looks like this

```
...
<!-- Scripts -->
    @livewireScripts
    @vite(['resources/css/app.css', 'resources/js/app.js'])
</head>
```

and my Js file is in the following path

> public/js/clientMovement/googleAutocompleteField.js

UPDATE
JS File:

```
function initMap() {
const buero = "/*Adresse*/";
const vonStrasse = document.getElementById("vonStrasse").value;
const vonStadt = document.getElementById("vonStadt").value;
const vonPLZ = document.getElementById("vonPLZ").value;
const nachStrasse = document.getElementById("nachStrasse").value;
const nachStadt = document.getElementById("nachStadt").value;
const nachPLZ = document.getElementById("nachPLZ").value;
const distanceInputField = document.getElementById("distance");
const distanceClientFromTo = document.getElementById("kundeKm");
const distanceKm = document.getElementById("gesamtKm");

const clientAddressFrom = vonStrasse + ', ' + vonPLZ + ' ' + vonStadt;
const clientAddressTo = nachStrasse + ', ' + nachPLZ + ' ' + nachStadt;


const request1 = {
    origins: [buero],
    destinations: [clientAddressFrom],
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
    unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,
    avoidHighways: false,
    avoidTolls: false,
};

const request2 = {
    origins: [clientAddressFrom],
    destinations: [clientAddressTo],
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
    unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,
    avoidHighways: false,
    avoidTolls: false,
};

const request3 = {
    origins: [clientAddressTo],
    destinations: [buero],
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
    unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,
    avoidHighways: false,
    avoidTolls: false,
};


// get distance matrix responses for all three legs
getDistanceMatrix(request1, function (response1) {
    getDistanceMatrix(request2, function (response2) {
        getDistanceMatrix(request3, function (response3) {
            // Combine distances from all three responses
            const totalDistance =
                response1.rows[0].elements[0].distance.value +
                response2.rows[0].elements[0].distance.value +
                response3.rows[0].elements[0].distance.value;

            const clientFromToDiestance =
                response2.rows[0].elements[0].distance.value;

            distanceInputField.value = totalDistance / 1000;
            distanceKm.value = totalDistance / 1000;
            distanceClientFromTo.value = clientFromToDiestance / 1000;

            /*console.log("Kunde: " + clientFromToDiestance / 1000 + " km");
            console.log("Distanz: " + totalDistance / 1000 + " km");*/

            const duration1 = response1.rows[0].elements[0].duration.value;
            const duration2 = response2.rows[0].elements[0].duration.value;
            const duration3 = response3.rows[0].elements[0].duration.value;

            totalDurationInSeconds = duration1 + duration2 + duration3;

            const totalDurationHours = totalDurationInSeconds / 3600;
            const roundedTotalDuration = roundToTwoDecimalPlaces(totalDurationHours);

            fahrtzeit.value = roundedTotalDuration;
            passValueToLivewire(roundedTotalDuration);
            
            //console.log("Gesamtdauer (Stunden): " + roundedTotalDuration);
        });
    });
});
}

function passValueToLivewire(value) {
console.log(value);
Livewire.emit('handleValue', value);
```

}

livewire component:

```
protected $listeners = ['handleValue'];
public function handleValue($value)
{
    //HANDLE VALUE HERE;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify if you are using Livewire 2.x or 3.x

Before accessing to the Livewire object you must ensure that it has been loaded/initialized.

For version 2.x :

```js
document.addEventListener('livewire:load', function () {
   Livewire.emit('handleValue', { value: "value" });
});
```

In the 3.x version you must listen to the *livewire:initialized* event and use the *dispatch()* method:

```js
document.addEventListener('livewire:initialized', () => {
   Livewire.dispatch('handleValue', { value: "value" });
});
```

Comment: Thank you already
I am using version 3.4.4
Unfortunately, the part within the function is not called at all.

Comment: Can you share more details of your code? My example shows how to fire a single event on startup, it must be customized to work in the real world

Comment: I have added a little more of my code

Comment: So, the right way to send the event is the second one I showed. However, the context is not well described, it is not clear how the *initMap()* function is included and how and when it is called, it is difficult to give a correct answer without knowing how everything is connected to Livewire

Comment: the trigger of initMap() is an input field. So if I enter something in an input field, this function is triggered